# Limitar Caracteres en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo que ingresar un texto de no mas de 10 caracteres, necesito hacer que el programa cuente los caracteres y si se sobrepasa hacérmelo saber. Repetirlo todas las veces que uno desee.

Esto es lo que llevo

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[10];
    int s, z, opc;
    int x = 0;
    bool valid = false;

    do {
        printf(a);
        cout<<"Escriba una frase:\n"<<endl;
        cin.getline(a, 10, '\n');
        if(cin.fail()) {
                valid=false;
            printf("No puede ser mayor a 10");
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        } else {
        valid =true;

        cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        cout<<"\n**************************\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Desea realizar otra prueba [1=Si] [2=No]\n";
        cin>>opc;
    } while(opc!=2 | !valid);
        if(opc==2){
        printf("\n Gracias \n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿ Cual es la pregunta ? ¿ Error de compilación ? ¿ Que error ? ¿ Los resultados no son los esperados ? ¿ Que esperas ? ¿ Que obtienes ? Deberías pasarte por [¿ Como elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: El código está bien en general. Solo veo un fallo, y es que no deberías llamar a `cin.ignore` cuando la entrada sí está bien. El `cin.clear` anterior es innecesario, pero no causa problemas. De lo contrario descartarás datos que aún no te han dado. Por otra parte, sería mejor si fueras consistente y usaras solo las funciones de `iostream` y no `stdio.h` o al revés. También que puedes lograr un efecto equivalente al de `system("pause")` con `cin.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion `size()` para saber el tamaño de un `char` y/o `string`

se utilizaria de la siguiente manera-->

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int contadordeletras(string frase_);
    bool comprobador(string frase_);
    
    
    int main(){
        string frase;
        cout << "introduce un frase: ";
        getline(cin, frase);
    
        if(comprobador(frase) == true){
            cout << "excede el numero de letras";
        }
        else if(comprobador(frase) == false){
            cout << "no excede el numero de letras";
        }
    }
    
    int contadordeletras(string frase_){
        string frase;
        frase = frase_;
        int numerodeletras;
        numerodeletras = frase.size();
        return numerodeletras;
    }
    
    bool comprobador(string frase_){
        bool comprobar = false;
        string copiadefrase = frase_;
        if(contadordeletras(copiadefrase) > 10){
            comprobar = true;
        }
        return comprobar;
    }
```

Lo he dividido en funciones para facilitar su implementación en tu código solo haz de pasar por referencia la frase que quieras introducir y la función `contadordeletras()`cuenta los caracteres que hay en una frase y `comprobador()` tedirá excede el limite que quieras establecer, espero que haya sido de ayuda